# displaying matched random numbers on a label

Tags: c#, winforms

I am beginner in c# and basically i generated random numbers in two  different listboxes but i wanted to write the numbers which are in both lists on a label . I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
 private void matchednumbers_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      lbluckynumbers.Items.Contains(lbmynumbers.Items).ToString();

    }
```

Comment: You mean any numbers that are in both lists?

Comment: no, i want to  write only same numbers in two listboxes .

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: for example , in first listbox i have 2,32,45,67,78 , and the second  listbox have   32,56,69,78,90  , so i want to write only 32, 78 because both numbers are included in boxes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you want to use [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to filter one of the collections, the condition is pretty simple, the other list contains it! So you start with something like:

```
IEnumerable<int> matches = firstCollection.Where(i => secondCollection.Contains(i));
```

Note that this algorithm is a bit... inefficent (O(n^2)) since you have to potentially run through all of secondCollection for every item in firstCollection. It will work for small sets just fine though.

Even better would be to use [`Intersect`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb460136%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which does all that work for you (and is usually O(2n) to boot!) :) (thanks @ScottChamberlain)

```
IEnumerable<int> matches = firstCollection.Intersect(secondCollection);
```

In both cases, I'm assuming n is approximately the same in both lists.

Now you need to convert that collection to text. [`String.Join`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876(v=vs.110).aspx) is super useful here, since it will take each element of a collection, call `ToString` to convert it to a string, and separate them with a string of our choice! Something like:

```
resultLabel.Text = String.Join(",", matches);
```

Comment: Since you are already using LINQ just use [`firstCollection.Intersect(secondCollection)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.100).aspx), it will be about `O(n1 + n2)` (where n1 and n2 represent each list) if the equality comparer has a good hash code.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Thanks, I always forget about the set functions.